# How do I create a zip file from a jar with dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to generate a zip file which contains:

- A fat jar
- Some other static .bat files

I tried to use `maven-assembly-plugin` because it seems to be able to do that.

Here is my attempt:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>some-application</name>
    <!-- ... -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-fat-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>my.company.some-application.SomeApplication</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**assembly.xml**

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
    <id>data-initialization-batch</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>compileDataInit.bat</source>
        </file>
        <file>
            <source>dataInit.bat</source>
        </file>
    </files>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <includes>
                <include>my.company:some-application:jar:jar-with-dependencies</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

This generates the following warning:

> [WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:
> o 'my.company:some-application:jar:jar-with-dependencies'

And the output zip file contains the bat files but no jar at all.

What makes me believe that this configuration should work is this sentence in the [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html):

> When the assembly is created it will use the assemblyId as the
> artifact's classifier and will attach the created assembly to the
> project so that it will be uploaded into the repository in the install
> and deploy phase.

Some more details:

- I have two executions because when I put one `descriptorRef` and one `descriptor` in the same `execution`, they are apparently unordered and can't depend on each other
- When I use `<include>my.company:some-application</include>` the regular jar gets properly included in the output zip, but I need the fat jar instead.

Comment: I'm sure you **can** do this, but are you *certain* it's what you really want? Are you aware a JAR file is ***literally*** a zip file with some extra metadata? You're planning to zip a zip.

Comment: If you want more context on why I'm trying to do this, I want to provide a jar along with bat files that contain `java -jar ...` with some interactions to retrieve the actual arguments. The user should be able to use it simply by unzipping the file and clicking on the bat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was just missing the `useProjectAttachments` option which is described in the [Assembly reference](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html)